# How to cascade delete when using inheritance and ManyToOne relationship with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm implementing a simple user managment system with spring. To achieve better model structure I use inheritance. The system is build on three classes. The `userdata` class which holds general information. The `parent` class which inherits and extends the user class and finally a `child` class which holds a parent object.

What I'm trying to do is to get all children (who are referred to a parent) deleted by deleting the `parent` object.

I'm already able to save/delete objects to/from my mySQL-DB over my view, so the repositories/services/controllers seem to work.

To give you better understanding of my situation I put some code below.

My `User` Class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserData implements Persistable<String> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@NotNull
private String username;
@NotNull
private String password;
@NotNull
private String firstName;
@NotNull
private String lastName;
```

My `Parent` Class which inherits from User and holds a set of Child:

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends UserData {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String imgName;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@ElementCollection
private Set<Child> children;
```

My `Child` class which holds a Parent object

```
@Entity
@Transactional
public class Child implements Persistable<Long> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String firstName;
@NotNull
private String lastName;
@NotNull
private String birthday;
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Parent parent1;
```

Hope anyone can tell me how I achieve `DELETE ON CASCADE` in my system.

Comment: Can you try adding `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}` into `@OneToMany` annotation?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I get `class org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException` ... maybe I need to add something to the `ManyToOne` too?

Comment: Yes, can you try adding `CascadeType.PERSIST` in both?

Comment: I already did but no success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `mappedBy = "parent1", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true` to the @OneToMany annotation in `parent` by `Set<Child> children` works.