# JPA Inheritance - parent is not deleted with child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

can you help with my deleting records with inheritance. I am using Entity manager for objects, and when I call em.remove(childInstance), is removed only child, and parent stay undeleted. Can you tell what I do wrong?

General table:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class General {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    // some other columns, getters and setters
}
```

Parent table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Parent extends General {

    // some columns and getters and setters
}
```

Child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_TABLE")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class Child extends Parent {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "main_child",
        nullable = true,
        columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
private Child mainChild;

@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "child")
private Set<MyObjectA> objects = new HashSet<>();

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    private Set<Child> subChildren = new HashSet<>();

    // some columns and getters and setters
}
```

MyObjectA class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "object_a")
public class MyObjectA extends General {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
    private Child child;
}
```

**EDIT: 1**
I forgot write that other entities refer to child object, and child object refer to itself.

**EDIT: 2**
I tried add to One To Many this:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true
```

and it return me that error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table
>   "parent" violates foreign key constraint
>   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" on table "child"

I look in database what that constraint is and it refer to that script:

```
ALTER TABLE public.child
  ADD CONSTRAINT xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES public.parent (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION; -- here should be ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: How did you check if the parent was deleted? By looking in the database or by analysing other entities that refer to parent?

Comment: looking to database

Comment: Then I have no clue. There are only a few minor differences between your setup and the one I typically use: 1) I have no `@Table` or `@OnDelete` annotations in most cases. 2) I use sequences for ID generation (one per entity table, so the IDs are not in my equivalent of your General class, but would in this case be defined in Parent)

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke check my update, I write relations with Child table.

Comment: Maybe this question+answer is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474984/how-to-cascade-delete-when-using-inheritance-and-manytoone-relationship-with-jpa

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke unfortunately isn't  :/ I update question with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting parent might fail because there are other children for that parent. Generally in order to delete parent of some child you in that case need to delete all siblings of that child also.

I am bit confused about your design and - in case you really meant to remove some parents all siblings with their children- you should

- make all related relationships between parent/child bi-directional
- make parent deletion to cascade to children also

For example, in child something like:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Parent parent;
```

and in parent

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="parent")
private Collection<Child> children;
```

In **your case** in Child

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
private Set<Child> subChildren = new HashSet<>();
```

should be changed to

```
// maps Child to itself bi-dir, note mappedBy changed form "id"
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mainChild", 
              cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) 
private Set<Child> subChildren = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: in parent I don't have any relations, only child is inherited from parent. And next for relations I use only child. So in physical database I have only FK in child which has reference to parent. And that tables has same number of records. So when child is deleted, must be parent also.

Comment: You have `@ManyToOne` unidirectional **relationship** `Child.mainChild`. So this mainChild (which extends Parent) might have other children. This _update or delete on table "parent" violates foreign key constraint  ... on table "child"_ tells it.

Comment: Yes, you have right, but how can I do bi-directional if child is in relationship with itself? Can you edit my classes in question to show me how please?

Comment: At quick glance in Child, subChildren mappedBy should be not "id" but "mainChild"